# After leaving the marines why did Aokiji join forces with pirates?

Tags: one-piece

Kuzan/Aokiji was once an Admiral of the World Government. After he lost in the battle for the Fleet Admiral position he left the marines and wander around on its own. And eventually a shocking news shock the World Government. Kuzan joined forces with

> Blackbeard pirates

which is regarded as a traitor to the government when he abuses his position as a Shichibukai.

> [image]
>   
>   **Question:** Why did he joined forces with the pirate group which is a traitor and a threat to the government? Does he not believe in justice anymore in the World Government?

Comment: While we don't have a strict no spoiler rule, please try to keep spoilers out of the title, especially for very new plot developments.

Comment: The reason is too unpredictable as there's too many probabilities.. We don't know the back story of it. It could most probably be that Aokiji has the intention of destroying the Blackbeard pirates from within by becoming a member. Or he must have accepted the Blackboard ideology. Or he decided to study the group's activities more closely (helping the Government as a spy). We won't have a clear answer for now.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder  @ʞɹɐzǝɹ. Sorry its my first time to post spoiler question here. I edited it and will take note of it next time I posts a spoiler question again.

Comment: he is a sleeper agent. . . because you know, Lazy Justice.

Answer (score 2):

Aokiji might have his own self justice principles.  As he has previously seen the unjustice rendered by the present fleet admiral to the innocent people of Ohara when Aokiji and Akainu are fellow comrade Vice Admirals in the buster call operation, he might feel indignant to work under a person (Akainu) who has the pretence of killing innocent in the name of justice as they contradict with his own self justice principles. So he might have decided to join hands with Black Beard who proclaims his evil intentions to the world rather than pretending to be someone.

But why he joined hands with Black Beard is the mystery.  Maybe Black Beard might have given him an approbation of making Aokiji the Fleet Admiral after he himself took the world dragons under captives and make Black Beard himself the new World Ruler. Simply a cruel, arrogant person is more detestable than a cruel, friendly person. Or he might be sick of the marines' overall cruel operations to safeguard the world government who follow tyrannical measures.

Answer (score 2):

I think aokiji is part of the revolution army and went in to the navy to spy
also I dont think aokiji really lost the fight,cause just because he lost the fight doesn't mean he would leave the navy, also when he showed at punk hazard he was pretty calm and told the navy not to tell anyone that he was there. I think aokiji purposely losed the fight to join blackbeard and spy that is all.

Comment: Welcome to [anime.se]. Thanks for contributing an answer, but could you add some references to back up your answer? Posting a personal theory is okay if they can be backed up by canonical source. Note that you can [edit] your answer to improve it. Finally, consider taking a quick [tour] to know more how this site works.